# Binary file path for Deploy to Visual Studio App Center

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I have the following build pipe line which I created using the Universal Windows Platform Template.

[image: build pipeline]

I want to deploy to the app center.

What do I put for the Binary File Path?

I see the help states

> Relative path from the repo root to the APK or IPA file you want to
>   publish

However there will be no APK files because the build does not make them.

Am I missing a task?

I tried

```
drop
```

I got an error

```
Error: Cannot find any file based on D:\a\1\s\drop.
```

[Update]
I edited this question to make it clearer I hope.

[Update]

I wonder if I need a Windows Application Packaging Project in the Repository?
[image: packaging project]

[Update]

It is clear from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/) that I cant use App Center to distribute to the store.

Never the less I assume App Center is still relevant to UWP. otherwise why would it even have a column in the support matrix and have a build task in a template called UWP?  Thus why do I get the error deploying to the App Center?

Comment: the error is in the last task? can you run the build with `system.debug` = true and share the logs?

Comment: Where do I set system.debug as true?

Comment: When you queue the build you have an option to change the value of `system.debug`

Comment: Regarding your update, the repo exists in the build server, you retrieve the code on the "Get sources" phase. in which task you created the APK/IPA file?

Comment: So you need to create the APK during the build, then to deploy to App Center (maybe the deployment will be in release pipeline and not in build pipeline).

Comment: It seems odd that the template creates a build task without having a task to create the APK file

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/platform-service-matrix

Answer (score 0):

"Visual Studio App Center" is for mobile applications like Android, iOS, Windows Phone etc., in these kinds of apps you have `.apk` file (for Android) or `.ipa` file (for iOS).

You have created a "Universal Windows Platform" application, is not a mobile app, you can't publish the app to VS App Center, so your last task is incorrect.

The template is fine, you build the application (UWP - apps run on all Windows 10 devices, from your TV to your tablet or PC) and the artifact is `.exe` file, like every windows application.

You can upload the application to the Windows Store with [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-RDX-MRO.windows-store-publish) task, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps) which are the steps to deploy to store.

Comment: Surely since I used the Universal Windows Template, and that contains a task to deploy to the app center then it is possible?

Comment: I checked nod and you right, it gives me this step but in Disable, I think because it gives you the option to upload to vs app center if you build a cross-platform app (in Xamarin, for example) and then you have uwp app and Android/iOS app. in your case, if it's just uwp app you don't need to use this step.

Comment: I want to put it in the store. Isn't the app center a necessary step to get to the store?  After all I can make .apk files by right click Deploy in Visual Studio.

Comment: When you deploy from vs to the store is not to vs app center, is to Windows Store, you need this task: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-RDX-MRO.windows-store-publish

Comment: You are right that you cant publish to the app store from the app center..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/  never the less it does seem to be on the radar.

Comment: but how do I deploy to the app center?

Comment: My mistake... please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730034/distribute-uwp-app-to-app-center-aka-mobile-center-using-vsts-task